# Validating input values in C#

Tags: c#, validation, lambda

I began studying C# 5.0 a few days ago and am trying to avoid duplicated code for validation of input values.

```
class transcript
{
  //Use lamda expression and Func for validation logic
  Func<byte, byte> validate = (grade) =>
  {
    if (grade > 100)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("grade can`t be more than 100");
    else
      return grade;
  };

  public string name { get; set; }

  public byte kor
  {
    get { return kor; }
    set { kor = validate(value); }
  }

  public byte eng
  {
    get { return this.eng; }
    set { eng = validate(value); }
  }
}
```

Comment: Funcs and delegates are cool, but really give their full power when you want to let a different class specify the behavior of this one. There's no reason not to just declare it as a regular ol' private method.

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks for your comment! I`m not native so it is little bit hard to understand could you say more easy? what is ol private method? you mean just declare set property logic each property?

Comment: No, I mean `private byte Validate(byte grade) { ... }`

Comment: @RubberDuck Oh I get it. I just try to get use to Func & Action, that`s it

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Capitalization Conventions on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx), types, methods, and properties should be `PascalCase`meaning they start with an uppercase letter.

---

```
  Func<byte, byte> validate = (grade) =>
  {
    if (grade > 100)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("grade can`t be more than 100");
    else
      return grade;
  };
```

There is no reason to use a `Func` here. Just use a normal method, like this

```
private byte Validate(byte grade)
{
    // the method body can go here
}
```

---

```
  public byte kor
  {
    get { return kor; }
    set { kor = validate(value); }
  }
```

Have you tested this code? The getter and setter both look like a StackOverflowException (via infinite recursion) to me. You need a backing field, like this

```
private byte kor;
public byte Kor
{
    get { return kor; }
    set { kor = Validate(value); }
}
```

---

It's uncommon to use `byte` instead of `int`, even if you know your data will fit in a byte. Only optimize for size if you know that you need to do so.

Comment: thanks. but I have a question why should I use int?. I used byte because it is not gonna be higher than 100

Comment: In .NET, your default choice to hold an integer should be `System.Int32` which is normally spelled `int` in C#. You should only use a different type if you have a reason to (working with a HUGE amount of data, interop with native code, etc...). Working with bytes can be awkward in C# - adding or subtracting bytes returns an `int` instead of a byte so you need to cast.

Comment: So you mean It is better for performance than even I use  Byte instead of Int?  Ok I`ll accepted. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here in this particular example, you can do the same with the help of getter and setter properties. they are capable of doing validations as well. with the help of  a back up variable you can achieve the target as like the following:

```
private byte _Grade;

public byte Grade
{
    get
    {
        return _Grade;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_Grade > 100)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("grade can`t be more than 100");
        else
            _Grade = value;
    }
}
```

So if you are trying to assign a value Greater than 100 it will throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: As I already said, I tried to avoid code duplicates and getting effective.